# how to delete directory from openshift data directory?

Tags: openshift

I have some folders/directories inside `$OPENSHIFT_DATA_DIR`. Now, I want to remove that directories.
Which command I should use to delete the directories.
 Please help me. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Google Linux commands

```
rm <folder or filename>
```